# How to continue executing the following script when an assertion fails in testcafe

Tags: testing, testcafe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahKFV.png)
The picture is for reference
1.How to display a passing assertion on the console?
2.If the second assertion fails, how to continue executing the next assertion?

I do a lot of operations in the browser and then get some js objects from browser in the testcafe. I don't want to split the use case and check the values separately, because the operation is continuous and I don't want to repeat the code, so I try to check all the values in one use case.I just want to know which values are expected and which are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. TestCafe does not show passing assertions in console. If you need this functionality, call the `console.log` method manually.
2. There is no official way to continue test execution after an assertion fails. You can wrap your assertion in the `try/catch` block. However, the TestCafe team does not recommend this approach.